# Release [Shared] MEF export

Tags: mvvm, mef

How does one properly release a viewmodel exported with the 
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)] flag?

I will like to use this viewmodel for a number of related views, but be able to completely release it when I move onto another module within the same application. Does the [Shared] attribute indicate an application lifetime existence?

Answer (score 1):

Shared means that one instance is shared between all imports. If you want a fresh instance of the view model every time you use it, you should use `NotShared`.